# why this code dont refresh the currently minute in real time?

Tags: python, datetime

the code shows the result only when executed. in the next minute it doesn't update instead it is the same result as the first minute.

all the best xP

```
t=datetime.datetime.now()

while True:
    nextminute=t.minute+1
    print("next M %s" %nextminute)
    print("M Curre %s" %t.minute)    
    time.sleep(61)    
print("loop end")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the value of the variable "t" is only set once before the while loop, meaning every time it is printed it will have the same value. To fix this you would need to put it inside the while loop so it is updated every minute, like so:

```
while True:
    t=datetime.datetime.now()
    nextminute=t.minute+1
    print("next M %s" %nextminute)
    print("M Curre %s" %t.minute)    
    time.sleep(61)    
print("loop end")
```

You also have a print statement at the end, this will never be ran as the loop is infinite (True will never be False), if you want to make the loop end you would need a counter, or something else that's value may change.

Comment: ho yes, thank you very much friend =]